# simple jquery fade in bg question

Tags: jquery

Im trying to have my background fade in onclick with jquery and im unsure on how to do it.
Here is my code:

```
$(".work").click( function(){ 
    $("body").removeClass('bg2 , bg3').addClass("bg1");
});

$(".about").click( function(){ 
    $("body").removeClass("bg1 , bg3").addClass("bg2");
});

$(".contact").click( function(){ 
    $("body").removeClass("bg1 , bg2").addClass("bg3");
});
```

thanks :D

Comment: That code will only add/remove css classes from your `<body>` element. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was hoping to have the backgrounds change on click but instead of just showing up fade in and out

Comment: you want to change the background color only?

Comment: and all classes have a `background-image` property right?

Comment: Yes, this thing currently works I just want to add the fading in and out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using the [jQuery UI plug-in](http://jqueryui.com/), they allow for the animation of color. You can do it like this:

```
$("body").animate({"background-color": "red"}, 1000);
```

And you can animate to any color you want. To give a "fade" effect, just have it animate out to white and then back into the color. If you are not using jQuery UI, this may add too much overhead to your site, so you might want to check out the [jquery.color plugin](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/blob/master/jquery.color.js). Only 4kb in size.

Here is an example of the fading using jQuery UI: http://jsfiddle.net/9VhpM/

**Update**

I didn't realize you were looking to fade the background image. You may find this helpful: [Image Loading | jQuery for Designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/)

Comment: im not animating color. I want to animate Background images.

Comment: @Robert - Ahhh...my mistake. Have you tried to do a search on Google. Lots of advice there - http://www.google.com/search?q=animate+background+images

Comment: @Robert - Updated my answer a bit.